# Updated registry values revert to their old values after I run "gpupdate /force"

Tags: windows, powershell, group-policy

I'm trying to apply local group policies, using `Set-ItemProperty` in `PowerShell`. If after that I run `gpupdate /force` the value reverts to the old one.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard -Name DeployConfigCIPolicy -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard -Name ConfigCIPolicyFilePath -Value ""
gpupdate /force
```

I also tried the `-Force` parameter but that didn't work either.

Comment: What’s the problem? It’s working as designed. You either change the gpo or the setting will keep going back

Comment: You cannot override Domain group policies using local GP settings. The domain GP will always override it when it refreshes.

Comment: @DougMaurer what do you mean by changing the gpo? what im trying to do is to automate the deployment of policies using powershell

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a problem with your code, this is how Group Policies (GPOs) are designed to work.** This is Microsoft's configuration management solution for **Active Directory** managed domains.

GPOs get reset the next time the policy is applied. So every time you run `gpupdate` this happens for any keys which are set by managed policies. This can potentially extend to some keys outside of the normal `Policies` path within the Registry when keys are set using a Registry Key policy. The only way to stop this behavior is to remove the conflicting setting from the managed GPO or no longer apply the offending GPO to your computer.

If you're not an Active Directory administrator, you'll likely need to talk to them if you feel have a strong enough case for disabling System Guard.

This behavior also extends to keys set by local policy using `gpedit.msc`, but similar to GPOs you need to be a local admin to edit the local computer policy. Note that local policies **cannot override GPOs**.

---

You can see the policies and settings applied by GPO using the following command:

```
gpresult /h report.html
```

This will run `rsop` and generate a nicely-formatted HTML page you can review to see which settings came from which policies.

Comment: I don't have gpo, is just a normal w10 pc, I'm making a script that scans and adds WDAC policy without any user interaction, so I just need to be able to enable/disable and add/eliminates the deviceGuard policy, is there any way to do that using powershell? (I have full admin permits)

Comment: Are you certain this setting isn't being controlled by your local policy? If you have Home that might change things since Home editions don't support local or group policies (the latter because there is no domain support).